# Using and testing UDP data over the internet

Tags: networking, tcp, udp

I have a GSM modem that sends data via UDP (it appears) I have configured it to send all data to my public IP address over the internet but no data is arriving at my end so I need to troubleshoot.

I have confirmed that a TCP connection can be made from anywhere on the internet on the same port that the modem is supposed to be communcating on.
Im using "Aggsoftware TCP/IP or UDP data logger" to listen for incoming data.

Is there software that I can use to test sending of UDP data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Netcat](http://joncraton.org/blog/46/netcat-for-windows) it will help you .

it  reads and writes data across network connections using the TCP/IP protocol  allows you to read and write data over a network socket .